# Powershell: How to stop start-job?

Tags: powershell

**I have the following job in powershell:**

```
$DoIt = '...'
....
 If ([IntPtr]::size -eq 8) {
        start-job { 
        param($a) IEX $a 
        } -RunAs32 -Argument $DoIt | wait-job | Receive-Job
        Get-Job | Stop-Job
        Exit
        Write-Host "exit powershell" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
}   
else {
    IEX $DoIt
}
```

**simply put, how to stop or close powershell after executing the `start-job` function. What should I do?Tried some ways to find that it didn't work.**

Comment: What is IEX? How does this code behave?

Comment: @Zergatul IEX invoke-expression

Comment: What do you meant by i want it to Quit after start job

Comment: simply put, how to stop or close powershell after executing the "start-job" function @TheGameiswar

Comment: stop-process -Id $PID

Comment: $pid is a global variable,which gives currently executing pid of powershell process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove-Job.  Here's an example.  If the job completes, you don't have to run stop-job.  Although invoke-expression is almost always the wrong answer, and you have to watch user input to it.  I'm in osx.

```
PS /Users/js> $job = start-job { param($a) sleep $a } -Args 3600
PS /Users/js> get-job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
11     Job11           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost             param($a) sleep $a

PS /Users/js> stop-job $job
PS /Users/js> remove-job $job  # or just remove-job -force
PS /Users/js> get-job  # none
```

Answer (score 2):

> how to stop or close powershell after executing the start-job function.

- If you exit your session *before* the background job launched with `Start-Job` has completed, you'll *stop* (abort) it *implicitly*, because **PowerShell cleans up pending background jobs automatically when the session that created them exits**.

  - Therefore, if you want to launch a background operation that *keeps running* when the session that initiated it exits, you'll have to use a different mechanism, such as `Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden ...` (Windows-only).
- To *wait* for the background job to finish, use `Wait-Job` or - combined with retrieving its output - `Receive-Job -Wait`.

  - Note that this is only useful if you perform *other actions* in between starting the background job and waiting for its completion - otherwise, you could just run the operations directly, without the need for a background job.